# IIS Forms Authentication (php, asp.net server side login)

Tags: authentication, iis-7.5, asp.net

We have multiple applications running on a single "site".

For example:
www.site.com/
www.site.com/app1
www.site.com/app2
etc...

Of these sites, some run PHP and some run ASP.net.

We've got Windows Authentication running and working now for all the sites. We're wondering if Forms Authentication by going through a ASP.net form will continue to authenticate the user across these other apps, even if they're PHP.

Simple question - but any other input would be nice!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default forms auth only applies to managed code.  However, you can make it apply to all types of files by going your site -> Modules and edit the FormsAuthentication module.  Uncheck the "Invoke only for requests to ASP.NET applications or managed handlers".

There's a slight performance penalty to have a managed module work for all files, but unless you have a really busy server, you won't notice it.